# Angular JS $scope $resource & Directive - Directive Loading faster than scope thus cant see data

Tags: angularjs

I am using an API to load (Data) to my $scope resource, and I took an example from a directive online to create a treeview. [Recursive Tree View Example](http://jsfiddle.net/n8dPm/)

However I am changing a few things to load data from an API. Please note the commented data... when I uncomment my data everything works great, however when I use `$scope.treeFamily = TreeView.query()` I think there is a delay between the directive executing and me getting no data. Any insight will be helpful. Thank you!

```
    var module = angular.module("module", ["ngResource", "ngRoute"]);

    module.factory('TreeView', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/TreeView/:Id', {}, {
            //show: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },  //<--- need to do query instead of show.... 
            query: { method: 'GET', isArray: false},
            update: { method: 'PUT', params: { id: '@id' } },
            delete: { method: 'DELETE', params: { id: '@id' } }
        })
    });

    module.controller('TreeCtrl', function ($scope, TreeView) {

        $scope.treeFamily = TreeView.query();

        //$scope.treeFamily = {
        //    name: "Parent",
        //    children: [{
        //        name: "Child1",
        //        children: [{
        //            name: "Grandchild1",
        //            children: []
        //        }, {
        //            name: "Grandchild2",
        //            children: []
        //        }, {
        //            name: "Grandchild3",
        //            children: []
        //        }]
        //    }, {
        //        name: "Child2",
        //        children: []
        //    }]
        //};
    });

    module.factory('RecursionHelper', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
        var RecursionHelper = {
            compile: function (element) {
                var contents = element.contents().remove();
                var compiledContents;
                return function (scope, element) {
                    if (!compiledContents) {
                        compiledContents = $compile(contents);
                    }
                    compiledContents(scope, function (clone) {
                        element.append(clone);
                    });
                };
            }
        };

        return RecursionHelper;
    }]);

    module.directive("tree", function (RecursionHelper) {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            scope: { family: '=' },
            template:
                '<p>{{ family.name }}</p>' +
                '<ul>' +
                    '<li ng-repeat="child in family.children">' +
                        '<tree family="child"></tree>' +
                    '</li>' +
                '</ul>',
            compile: function (element) {
                return RecursionHelper.compile(element);
            }
        };
    });
```

The Result from what i get there using the following HTML.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="module">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div ng-controller="TreeCtrl">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="result in treeFamily">
                    <td> From Table: {{result.name}}</td>
                </tr>

            </table>

            <tree family="treeFamily"></tree>
        </div>
        <div ng-view=""></div>
    </div>
```

**Result :** 
Name
From Table: Parent

HOWEVER, this is from the the ng-repeat within my table, so i know the API is sending DATA and it is readable.

```
{
ID: "1",
type: "Folder",
name: "Parent",
children: []
}
```

The problem is that it seems that the directive is not loading this data.... If however uncomment the built in data I have for that scope it works fine...

I have a feeling that my directive is loading faster than my API call so I get no data. Am i doing something wrong?

Any help will be appreciated!

---

**Additional Research...**

$scope.treeFamily = { "ID": "1", "type": "Folder", "name": "Harvest", "children": null };
$scope.treeFamily = [{ "ID": "1", "type": "Folder", "name": "Harvest", "children": null }];

This is the difference.....

If i try to do ng-repeat on 
$scope.treeFamily = { "ID": "1", "type": "Folder", "name": "Harvest", "children": null };

It will not work because it is expecting an object [...] 
$scope.treeFamily = [{ "ID": "1", "type": "Folder", "name": "Harvest", "children": null }];
Thus the above will work.

However, when using the recursive tree, it seems as though it does not EXPECT to see an object other than children... thus

$scope.treeFamily = [{ "ID": "1", "type": "Folder", "name": "Harvest", "children": null }];

will fail......

HOWEVER, I changed my API to return like this:
{ "ID": "1", "type": "Folder", "name": "Harvest", "children": null }
It still wont work!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably an Angular version issue. Automatic promise unwrapping was [removed in version 1.2](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#templates-no-longer-automatically-unwrap-promises). Change the code to:

```
var treeFamily = TreeView.query(function(){
    $scope.treeFamily = treeFamily;
});
```

or use the more explicit promise syntax:

```
TreeView.query().$promise.then(function(treeFamily){
    $scope.treeFamily = treeFamily;
});
```

Comment: Nice thanks! Best answer, however I did have a problem in my code... I was doing show instead of query....

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the order matters. Since in [the documentation of $resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource) it says:

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data. This is a useful trick since usually the resource is assigned to a model which is then rendered by the view. Having an empty object results in no rendering, once the data arrives from the server then the object is populated with the data and the view automatically re-renders itself showing the new data. This means that in most cases one never has to write a callback function for the action methods.

Are you sure data is returned from the server?

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. This is what the data looks like from the api.  <ArrayOfTreeView xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/">
<TreeView>
<ID>1</ID>
<Name>Parent</Name>
<Type>Folder</Type>
</TreeView>
</ArrayOfTreeView>

Comment: This is not JSON, so obviously it would not work. AngularJS $resource and $http work with json data.

Comment: <ArrayOfProduct xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/">
<Product>
<Category>Groceries</Category>
<Id>1</Id>
<Name>Tomato Soup</Name>
<Price>1</Price>
</Product>
<Product>
<Category>Toys</Category>
<Id>2</Id>
<Name>Yo-yo</Name>
<Price>3.75</Price>
</Product>
</ArrayOfProduct>   In a different example this works just fine.         var ProductsController = function ($scope, $location, Products) {

            //This gets the main load.... gets the list from the service.
            $scope.products = Products.query();

Comment: Changed API to send JSON instead of IEnumerable: [
{
ID: "1",
type: "Folder",
name: "Harvest",
children: null
}
]  -- Still wont work unless i need to have children []

Comment: Am returning JSON insgead of IEnumerable, [ { ID: "1", type: "Folder", name: "Harvest", children: []}] still not working.....

Comment: It seems as though it is, I must have something wrong with my angular code in how its working. JSON returns just fine, if i change the code to just do ng-repeat i get all the data.. but when i try to use a created directive it wont work.